# HTML/CSS Stylesheet won't work

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

<strike>I'm probably missing something really obvious but why won't this code work?</strike>

```
<link type="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
```

Basically, I'm trying to get a stylesheet that is called `main.css` in a folder called `css`.

I don't know why it won't work so please help me!

## *Probelm Solved*

Comment: What's your folder structure? Is the path correct?

Comment: you are such a incredible genius man...what a way to show that your problem has been solved....

Comment: Compliment or Insault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong syntax:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
      ^^^              ^^^^
```

Note the attributes...

Comment: Wow im so dumb... such an obvious error of mine! LOL

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this**

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```